# Hook into Windows sizing events: hook is not called

Tags: winapi, hook

I'm trying to hook into Windows' sizing events. I wrote the following hook:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProcedure(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MSG *msg = (MSG *)lParam;

    wchar_t text[1014];
    GetWindowText(msg->hwnd, text, 1024);

    if (wcscmp(text, L"Untitled - Notepad") == 0)
    {
        if (nCode == HCBT_MOVESIZE)
        {
            FILE *file;
            fopen_s(&file, "C:\\Users\\Me\\hooklog.txt", "a+");
            fprintf(file, "Move or size.\n");
            fclose(file);
        }
        else
        {
            FILE *file;
            fopen_s(&file, "C:\\Users\\Me\\hooklog.txt", "a+");
            fprintf(file, "Something else.\n");
            fclose(file);
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And I'm tring to install it using:

```
HHOOK hhk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, hookProc, hModule, 0);
DWORD err = GetLastError();
```

The same technique works for other types of hooks, but fot WH_CBT is not working. All the variables (**hookProc**, **hModule** ad **hhk** after the call, and **err** is *0*) involved have reasonable values and there are no signs of error. In the log file nothing shows up.

**Working version**

I had noticed that nCode usage depends on the type of hook, but I completely forgot to check the other parameters; as Hans noticed **lParam** doesn't point to a **MSG** for **WH_CBT** with **nCode == HCBT_MOVESIZE**; instead, **lParam** points to the new **RECT** and the **HWND** can be retrieved from **wParam**.

```
__declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProcedure(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_MOVESIZE)
    {
        wchar_t text[1014];
        GetWindowText((HWND)wParam, text, 1024);

        if (wcscmp(text, L"Untitled - Notepad") == 0)
        {
            RECT *rect = (RECT *)lParam;

            FILE *file;
            fopen_s(&file, "C:\\Users\\Me\\hooklog.txt", "a+");
            fprintf(file, "Move or size (%d, %d, %d, %d) for target window.\n", rect->left, rect->right, rect->top, rect->bottom);
            fclose(file);
        }
        else
        {
            FILE *file;
            fopen_s(&file, "C:\\Users\\Me\\hooklog.txt", "a+");
            fprintf(file, "Move or size for some other window.\n");
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        FILE *file;
        fopen_s(&file, "C:\\Users\\Me\\hooklog.txt", "a+");
        fprintf(file, "Something else.\n");
        fclose(file);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Installing a global hook to monitor just one window is overkill. Use an accessibility hook filtered to the thread that owns the window you care about.

Comment: This will be very useful, I was wondering whether there was a way to be more selective, thanks! Just to make sure I understood, are you talking about **SetWinEventHook** and **WinEvents** ? I had seen those in the docs, but wasn't sure if they were good for my case or not.

Comment: @damix911 yes, "accessibility hook filtered to the thread" implies SetWinEventHook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption that the passed lParam is a pointer to a MSG is just wrong.  Check the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the callback, scroll to the bottom.  You'll see that when nCode == HCBT_MOVESIZE then lParam is a pointer to RECT.

`wParam` gives you the handle to the window.

Code defensively, never ignore winapi function return values.

Comment: Thank you, I first wrote a functioning hook for **WH_GETMESSAGE** and I totally failed to check parameter semantics when I switched to **WH_CBT**.